# Multi path update in Firebase issue with more than two locations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update 8 locations at a time in Firebase, using the Swift SDK. Somehow I managed to update the first two, but the other six only writes to the father node, and lost its correspondent path. Below is the data of my Firebase DB that illustrates the issue better:

```
    {
  "districts" : {
    "did01" : {
      "name" : "Teusaquillo",
      "peopleids" : {
        "stateid01" : true,
        "stateid02" : true,
        "stateid03" : true
      },
      "schools" : {
        "schoolid01" : {
          "location" : "norte 50 grados sur 42 ",
          "name" : "Agustiniano Salitre",
          "posts" : {
            "eighth" : {
              "nola" : "hola"
            },
            "eighth-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
            "eleventh" : {
              "name" : "haka"
            },
            "eleventh-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
            "fifth" : {
              "-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
              "dsadsad" : {
                "name" : "Hola"
              },
              "dsfsdfdsf" : true
            },
            "first" : {
              "1" : {
                "author" : "Giovanny Piñeros",
                "text" : "Test"
              },
              "01" : {
                "author" : "Giovanny Piñeros",
                "text" : "Capo"
              },
              "abdffg" : {
                "author" : "Gio",
                "text" : "hola"
              },
              "fdgfdg" : {
                "author" : "Giovanny Piñeros",
                "text" : "Hola"
              },
              "nfdsfds" : {
                "author" : "Giovanny Piñeros",
                "text" : "Vivir de lo que amo"
              },
              "postid01" : {
                "author" : "Papa frita",
                "text" : "Hola",
                "topic" : "Informatics",
                "year" : "first"
              },
              "rtyrty" : {
                "author" : "Giovanny Piñeros",
                "text" : "Si con headapp solo sabia manejar strings y colores, imaginate ahora lo que puedo crear"
              },
              "zsadsa" : {
                "author" : "Gio",
                "text" : "Trest"
              }
            },
            "fourth" : {
              "name" : "hqiq"
            },
            "fourth-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
            "ninth" : {
              "hola" : "ahah"
            },
            "ninth-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
            "postid01" : {
              "-KaG0b-X9sWXxXlXlmeK" : "angela",
              "-KaG0wNu0Gz5oxu4__Ej" : "angela",
              "author" : "Papa frita",
              "likes" : {
                "userid01" : "Giovanny Piñeros"
              },
              "text" : "hola",
              "topic " : "Informatics",
              "year" : "first"
            },
            "postid02" : {
              "autor" : "Directive",
              "text" : "Free for the day",
              "topic" : "General",
              "year" : "all"
            },
            "second" : {
              "-KaFnTl89keEOx3UpnGJ" : true,
              "-KaFpLsNy6z-TshUJONx" : true,
              "-KaFpMwBdHqBwsq-k6i3" : true,
              "-KaFpz6qwQ2uTevvpxXo" : true,
              "-KaFq21Qdv-Z6KFcu8ZT" : true,
              "-KaFq34fN1-ZxO0EtqEw" : true,
              "-KaFv7a9JvEjPLDDzT8S" : "angela",
              "-KaFw9Hb6OjIRzeP6jdk" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAFvFoVEvpzaaVO2" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAboyWtEOG3NU1yZ" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAji3rR6e5fCHjFc" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAmisIA5i4UhvcRw" : "angela",
              "-KaFyJHEqDzoVoj_zUWI" : "angela",
              "-KaFy_cqf1mvTxRGN5j_" : "angela",
              "-KaG-_r4ql2YVc19gbkt" : "angela",
              "dsfsdf" : {
                "hola" : "dfsad"
              }
            },
            "seventh" : {
              "name" : "dsfhksd"
            },
            "sixth" : {
              "name" : "haaka"
            },
            "tenth" : {
              "name" : "hola"
            },
            "tenth-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
            "third" : {
              "-KaFnTl89keEOx3UpnGJ" : true,
              "-KaFpLsNy6z-TshUJONx" : true,
              "-KaFpMwBdHqBwsq-k6i3" : true,
              "-KaFpz6qwQ2uTevvpxXo" : true,
              "-KaFq21Qdv-Z6KFcu8ZT" : true,
              "-KaFq34fN1-ZxO0EtqEw" : true,
              "-KaFv7a9JvEjPLDDzT8S" : "angela",
              "-KaFw9Hb6OjIRzeP6jdk" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAFvFoVEvpzaaVO2" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAboyWtEOG3NU1yZ" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAji3rR6e5fCHjFc" : "angela",
              "-KaFwAmisIA5i4UhvcRw" : "angela",
              "-KaFyJHEqDzoVoj_zUWI" : "angela",
              "-KaFy_cqf1mvTxRGN5j_" : "angela",
              "-KaG-_r4ql2YVc19gbkt" : "angela",
              "-KaG0b-X9sWXxXlXlmeK" : "angela",
              "-KaG0wNu0Gz5oxu4__Ej" : "angela",
              "-KaG1PA5r7cl70FtBsE4" : "angela",
              "author" : "hola"
            },
            "twelfth" : {
              "name" : "haoao"
            }
          },
          "users" : {
            "userid01" : {
              "likes" : {
                "postid01" : true
              },
              "name" : "Giovanny Piñeros",
              "rol" : "student",
              "stateid" : "stateid01",
              "year" : "first"
            },
            "userid03" : {
              "Posts" : {
                "postid01" : {
                  "fjsldkfj" : "nombre",
                  "texzto" : "fksdjh"
                }
              },
              "name" : "Papa frita",
              "rol" : "teacher"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "did02" : {
      "name" : "Austin",
      "peopleids" : {
        "stateid04" : true,
        "stateid05" : true,
        "stateid06" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "eventos" : {
    "attendiees" : {
      "adshfksafjh" : "giovanny"
    },
    "nombre" : "fiesta"
  },
  "queue" : {
    "specs" : {
      "specstest" : 0
    },
    "tasks" : {
      "ido" : {
        "_error_details" : {
          "error" : "Task was malformed",
          "error_stack" : "Error: Task was malformed\n    at Object.update (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-queue/dist/lib/queue_worker.js:453:27)\n    at Ih (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:233:395)\n    at R.h.transaction (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:248:466)\n    at /Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-queue/dist/lib/queue_worker.js:446:30\n    at c (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:135:58)\n    at /Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:126:791\n    at Ac (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:63:165)\n    at jf (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:126:215)\n    at hf (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:125:479)\n    at vf (/Users/Giovanny/Dropbox/Proyectos/NotifyMe/NotifyMeServer/notifymeserver/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:231:426)",
          "original_task" : 0
        },
        "_state" : "error",
        "_state_changed" : 1482958978549
      }
    }
  },
  "usuarios" : {
    "hvlksdj" : {
      "edad" : 26,
      "nombre" : "giovanny"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the child nodes `postid01` and `second` are updated, creating a new child, but for the other locations, this doesn't happen.

Here is my code. I did the following according to the Firebase guidelines:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var newPost = ref.childByAutoId()
let newKey = newPost.key  
let dict = ["districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/fifth/\(newKey)" : "test","districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/third/\(newKey)": "test",
                "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/fourth\(newKey)": "test","districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/postid02\(newKey)": "test",
                "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/sixth\(newKey)": "test","districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/seventh\(newKey)": "test",
        "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/eighth\(newKey)": "test", "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/ninth\(newKey)": "test", "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/tenth\(newKey)": "test", "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/eleventh\(newKey)": "test", "districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/postid04\(newKey)" : "test"]

ref.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {(Error,FIRDatabaseReference) in
    if(Error == nil){
    print("EXITO :)")
    }else{
    print("PAILA :(")
    }
    })
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, im posting the JSON

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen and AL. for your help, i've just found the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the error, it was so simple, i make a mistake on the dictionary. The locations that weren't updated were written like this :

```
"districts/did01/schools/schoolid01/posts/fourth\(newKey)": "test"
```

As you can see the last part is missing a "/" just before the newKey.